# Prevent full page zoom

Tags: jquery, css, html, touch, pinchzoom

I have a page with a svg map at the half top area and an index at the half bottom area. This page is going to be displayed on touch screen. I want to isolate the index (bottom area) from being zoomed when using *touch-action:pinch-zoom* on the top area (map) . I tried using an iframe for the top but it keeps zooming the full page

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the header of your HTML doc
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`

Keep the `touch-action:pinch-zoom` on the map.